# Using the value of a variable to access a property of an object

Tags: javascript

```
var fruit = {apple:"1", banana:"2"};
var w = "apple";

console.log(fruit.w); //this is problematic
```

I am trying to use this logic in my code to display the value "1" in the console.  This doesn't work.  Intuitively, this makes sense, as `console.log(fruit.w);` is equivalent to `console.log(fruit."apple");`, which because of the quote symbols is non-sense.  So how can I modify this code to work?

Comment: see mdn about [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
console.log(fruit[w]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's why that doesn't work. It's all about scope. When you call `fruit.w`, it's looking for the property `w` that belongs to the `fruit` object, instead of the value of global variable `w` in the object `fruit`.

Instead, you can use `[w]`, which uses the value of global `w` as the name of the property for object `fruit`.

**Note:** Global is used in the context of the code block this resides in.

```
var fruit = {apple:"1", banana:"2"};
var w = "apple";

console.log(fruit[w]); // Produces '1'
```

This uses the value of the variable as the property by this notation.

This snippet should illustrate the point.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fruit = {
    apple: "1",
    banana: "2"
  };
  var w = "apple";
  $(".apple").text(fruit[w]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apple"></div>
```

Further Reading:

[MDN Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) (Thanks @Grundy)